# Help Identifying plant?

Tags: identification

It started growing in one of the pots, but I have no idea what it is. It doesn’t look like a weed even though it’s growing at full sun and 90+ degree weather.
[image]

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. What part of the world are you in? Did you grow anything in these pots before? Where did you get the soil/potting mix from? Does the plant have an odor? Please use the [edit] link to add the information to your post.

Answer (score 2):

According to [plantnet](https://identify.plantnet.org/), this seems to be [Peperomia pellucida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia_pellucida). Please double check, especially if you try to use it as food (even better: triple-check it).

Comment: Based on the "rat-tail" like flowers it certainly is a Peperomia of some kind.